# Bad Request - Invalid URL during the terraform apply

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, azure-rm

I use terraform to deploy virtual resources accross differents Azure Subscriptions. I use a service principal.

There is only one subscription in which I can't deploy and I have the error below :

```
▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ Terraform Apply ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
data.azurerm_key_vault.compute_lab: Reading...
data.azurerm_resource_group.image: Reading...
data.azurerm_shared_image.image: Reading...
data.azurerm_resource_group.image: Read complete after 0s [id=/subscriptions/((redacted))/resourceGroups/Packer]
data.azurerm_shared_image.image: Read complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/((redacted))/resourceGroups/Packer/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/cycloid/images/Windows-server-2019]
data.azurerm_key_vault.compute_lab: Read complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/((redacted))/resourceGroups/COMPUTE-LAB-COM/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/COMPUTE-LAB]
╷
│ Warning: Invalid index:The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
│ 
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: resources.ProvidersClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"\r\n\r\n\r\n
Bad Request - Invalid URL
\r\n
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

\r\n\r\n" '\x00' '\x00'} error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 1, in provider "azurerm":
│    1: provider "azurerm" {
│ 
╵

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ Terraform Apply ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲ ▲
Failed To Run Terraform Apply!
2023/05/31 08:28:43 Apply Error: Failed to run Terraform command: exit status 1
```

It's just supposed to "connect" to the subscription to deploy what I need to deploy.

**Azure RM terraform provider version:** 3.54.0

**Terraform version:** v1.4.6

What I've checked:

- Service principal credentials are all good.
- Service principal permissions are the same on all the subscriptions.
- The resource provider in the subscription settings are all the same and setup well.
- No network issue

Here are the code snippet:

**versions.tf**

```
##################################################################################
# VERSIONS
##################################################################################

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.54.0"
    }
    /*
    netbox = {
      source  = "e-breuninger/netbox"
      version = "1.5.1"
    }*/
    awx = {
      source  = "nolte/awx"
      version = "0.2.2"
    }

    }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  features {}

  alias           = "common-services"
  subscription_id = var.common_services_id
}

resource "random_password" "admin_pwd" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}


data "azurerm_resource_group" "" {
  name = var.resource_group
}


## Import Key vault informations ##
data "azurerm_key_vault" "compute_lab" {
  provider            = azurerm.common-services
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_keyvault
}
```